# Insert a DataRow inside a table

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2005

I have a function that returns a typed `DataRow` object and now I would insert this `DataRow` in a given table. [As far as I know](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233812%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) I could do this using `TableAdapter` in two ways: `TableAdapter.Update` and `TableAdapter.Insert`.

Both ways seems pretty simple to use but, first way could even delete row from the table (essentially my `DataSet` will be "serialized" on my DB table) and since this table is really the application's critical part I would avoid any chance of data deletion, so I would prefear `Insert` method.

The problem seems to be that `Insert` method doesn't accept a `DataRow` object as it's parameter (unlike `Update`), so I need to manually insert each parameters. Alas I have at least 80 parameters so this is a really really headache operation. What can I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The update method does allow you to insert,update or delete changes in the tableAdapter. MSDN: 'Use the TableAdapter.Update method when your application uses datasets to store data. The Update method sends all changes (updates, inserts, and deletes) to the database'. Although Insert is ment for usage if you want more control for you data inserts but does not allow you to pass a datarow instead Parameters must be used. See complete reference on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233812(v=vs.110).aspx

Code example of Update method usage.

```
// Create a new row.
NorthwindDataSet.RegionRow newRegionRow;
newRegionRow = northwindDataSet.Region.NewRegionRow();
newRegionRow.RegionID = 5;
newRegionRow.RegionDescription = "NorthWestern";

// Add the row to the Region table 
this.northwindDataSet.Region.Rows.Add(newRegionRow);

// Save the new row to the database 
this.regionTableAdapter.Update(this.northwindDataSet.Region);
```

Code example Insert:

```
NorthwindDataSetTableAdapters.RegionTableAdapter regionTableAdapter = 
new NorthwindDataSetTableAdapters.RegionTableAdapter();

regionTableAdapter.Insert(5, "NorthWestern");
```